# Two IP Address match

Tags: sql, regex, ip-address

I need to match two ipaddress with a **regular expression**:
Like 20.20.20.20

```
should match with      20.20.20.20
should match with      [http://20.20.20.20/abcd]
should not match with  20.20.20.200
should not match with  [http://20.20.20.200/abcd]
should not match with  [http://120.20.20.20/abcd]
```

At present i am using something like this regular expression: `".*[^(\d)]20.20.20.20[^(\d)].*"`
But it is not working for the 1st and 3rd case.Please help me with this regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ignoring the case where the line starts with 20.20.20.20:

```
"(.*[^(\d)]|^)20.20.20.20([^(\d)].*|$)"
```

seems to work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
select * from tablename
where ip = '20.20.20.20' or ip like 'http://20.20.20.20/%'
```

Comment: Your solution is ok but looking at tags I think he wants a regular expression.

Comment: @cad it's possible, let's see what the OP says.

Comment: @aF thanks for the solution. I needed regular expression for this.

Answer (score 0):

`[^(\d)]` without quantifier means that you expect exactly 1 characer that is not a number
using `[^(\d)]*` will help

Comment: thanks for the finding the problem with regex. it is working nw :)